# How many $6$-permutations of $[15]$ have their digits listed in increasing order?

Tags: combinatorics

$[15]$ is the set of first $15$ naturals. In my textbook permutation means a sequence without repetition.

There are $15 \cdot 14 \cdot 13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10$ permutations. For each word like $123456$ there's a word like $654321$. So to remove the words of decreasing order we could probably divide $15 \cdot 14 \cdot 13 \cdot 12 \cdot 11 \cdot 10$ by $2$. But there are also words that are neither of decreasing, nor of increasing order. I am stumped here. Some kind of hint and/or comment would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to look at the number of ways you can choose $6$ elements out of $15$ -- the order is already imposed on you (once the elements are chosen, there is only one way you can order them).

Answer (score 0):

There's only one permutations which is increasing given a sequence of 6 distinct numbers. In your example, using 1 to 6, only 123456 is increasing.
 So you will just have to calculate how many subsets of 6 elements you can get from [15]. 
Simple combinations will do.